# Crystal Reports with large data takes long time to load

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm currently working on upgrading a windows application from VB6 to VB.NET. One of the components of the application includes Crystal Reports. I'm extremely new with VB and Crystal Reports in general so I needed some help.

Let me start off by saying I got the report to pull the correct data and there are no syntactical errors but When ever I try and pull data with numerous records it takes a very long time to load. Ex. one of the queries includes 16000+ rows returned, in the VB6 version it takes ~1.5 seconds but in the .Net version it took 18 minutes. I'm sure there's things I can do to make the report more efficient but since I haven't worked with it enough I needed help to get on the right track. I'm having no issues what so ever when the report is trying to pull small amount of data.

To generate the report I'm using datasets and I think this is the part that's slowing down the load time. Below is the example of the way I have SQL Query set up and the way I have my datasets set up.

```
sSQLQry = “SELECT [COLUMN_NAMES] from Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 WHERE [condition] ORDERBY col1,col2,col3 ASC

    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sSQLQry, cnn)
    Dim ds As New my_dataset

    dscmd.Fill(ds, "table1")
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "table2")
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "table3")
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "table4")

    crystalreport1.SetDataSource(ds)

    CrystalReportViewer1.Height = Me.Height
    CrystalReportViewer1.Width = Me.Width
    CrystalReportViewer1.Show()
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalreport1
```

Now I think the reason why it's slow is because of the 4 fill methods but I'm not sure how to combat that issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this code i use it in c# and oracle database but im sure it can help u:

```
        CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable T;

        for (int i = 1; i <= report1.Database.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            T = (CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable)report1.Database.Tables[i];
            CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperties cps = T.ConnectionProperties;
            CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperty cp =
                (CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperty)cps["User ID"];
            cp.Value = "Username" ;
            cp = (CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperty)cps["Password"];
            cp.Value = "Password" ;
            cp = (CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperty)cps["Data Source"];
            cp.Value = "DataSource" ;
            T.SetLogOnInfo("DataSource", "", "Username", "Password");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports has a known issue with multiple tables in an ADO.NET datasource.  It is really slow linking the data.

What we had to do to get around this was to create the data in a single table (flat file) and then the reports are very fast. They have had this issue for ever and are not doing anything about it, so don’t hold your breath that they will get it fixed soon.

See this [SAP ADO.NET Datasource Slow](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1527613)